# Image not getting loaded in HTML

Tags: angularjs, node.js, image, mongodb, imagedownload

I have created a `Node-Webkit` application using `AngularJS` in front-end and `NodeJS` in backend. I am trying to load an image into my application. It works fine if the internet is fast. But at times,if internet is slow it doesn't get loaded. I couldn't figure out what the issue is. Whenever I want to load an image I call a service to my node server, and from the node server it loads and sends image from `MongoDB`.

Here is my code to load image from DB:

```
var profilePicture = require('skipper-gridfs')({
    uri: 'mongodb://' + config.fileUploadDownload.url + ':27017/' +     config.fileUploadDownload.db + '.Media'
});
profilePicture.read(params, function (err, downloadedFile) {
    if (err) {
        res.send("found an error");
    } else {
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'image/png');
        res.send(downloadedFile);
    }
});
```

And this is my code for rendering the image in HTML:

`<img ng-src="{{img_url}}" class="prof-ico">` //`img_url` is the url to download image from backend

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you first check that the image loads when manually typing the image url in the address bar?

Comment: Yes. I tried that. Its getting loaded. But it takes time. Its loading slowly only.

Comment: This issue is solved.. I had written all my code for fetching the image from MongoDB in my service which was called from a controller. When I wrote the code for fretching the image straight inside the controller, it worked. It's loading slowly but the image gets completed loaded in client-end.